# I have my own portfolio designed with bootstrap4 &I had used modal for feedback,I need to get feedback of visitors,in Google Sheet without Google Form

Tags: html, google-sheets, bootstrap-4, google-sheets-api, google-sheets-query

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tW6Ph.png)

this image is of my bootstrap modal from modal I wanna to get feedback of visitors
I had hosted this portfolio in HTML I need to get feedback without any database using google sheet.

Answer (score 0):

### To give a general answer to your general question:

- If you are using a custom HTML form allowing the users to input their feedback, you can incorporate this HTML form into a [Google Web App](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- You can implement a JS script function that will retreive the input values on Form submit client side
  +You can call within the JS function a server-side Apps Script function with  parameters with [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)
- Within the Apps script function you can write the input values as desired into a spreadsheet.

**Sample:**

HTML file index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
 <form id="test-form">
        <div>
            <label>Field 1</label>
            <input type="text" name="field_1" placeholder="Field 1" />
        </div>

        <div>
            <label>Field 2</label>
            <input type="text" name="field_2" placeholder="Field 2" />
        </div>

            <button type="submit" id="submit-form" onclick="myJSFunction()">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>
  <script> 
 function myJSFunction(){
 var data=[];
   data.push(document.getElementsByName("field_1")[0].value);
   data.push(document.getElementsByName("field_2")[0].value);

   google.script.run.handleResponse(data);
 }
</script> 
  </body>
</html>
```

.gs file

```
function doGet(e){
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');  
    }
function handleResponse(data) {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('YOUR SPREADSHEET ID').getSheetByName(SHEETNAME);
 sheet.getRange('A1').setValue(data[0]);
 sheet.getRange('B1').setValue(data[1]);
}
```